# undefined local variable or method 'faq'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I run `http://localhost:3000` I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `faq_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb238145c20>:0x007fb235054b98>
Extracted source (around line #12):

   <body>
   <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
   <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
   <%= link_to "Faq", faq_path %>
   <%= yield %>
   </body>
   </html>
```

My routes file

```
Document::Application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
  get "faq" => "pages#faq"
```

My pages Controller file

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def faq
  end
end
```

And my layouts file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
<%= link_to "About", about_path %>
<%= link_to "Faq", faq_path %>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I get when I run `rake routes` 
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern      Controller#Action
     root GET /                pages#home
    about GET /about(.:format) pages#about
      faq GET /faq(.:format)   pages#faq

Comment: can you show us your route list? Just type in the console `rake routes` or better `bundle exec rake routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the route to `get "faq" => "pages#faq", :as => :faq`

Unless you've defined it elsewhere in `routes.rb`, you're likely to see the same issue for `about_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `match` in you `routes.rb` file, like this:

`match '/faq',     :to => 'pages#faq'`